# Converting large byte array to numeric string using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, biginteger

I am facing a issue in which I need to convert a byte array of roughly the size in range of 20 - 28 bytes into a printable number string. In Java I am able to do it easily using BigInteger Class. In Objective C, the biggest type is Long Long Int which is only 64 bits. Please guide me the approach to solve the problem. I am not good in C language but some examples will be highly helpful. I must admit, I would be in the same problem in Java if the BigInteger Class was not there in Java as well.

Comment: Does the number need to be printed in base-10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this source: 
http://www.santsys.com/code/display?folder=Objective-C&file=BigInt.h

**EDIT:**

Check the [BitInt class](http://www.santsys.com/code/display?folder=Objective-C&file=BigInt.h), a big integer implementation in Objective-C, so you do not need to use C to solve your problem, and it's methods are similar to that of Java.

Comment: Link only answers on SO are not preferred, as they can suffer from link rot. Please at least include some excerpts from the link you gave, instead of trusting us to click a link from a site we may not have seen before.

Comment: The `BigInt` class is wonderful! Exactly what I was looking for. A `.h` and `.m` file you easily add to your project, and everything works perfectly! Thanks a bunch!